# WiFi is connected but WiFi icon not showing ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless

> This is my first question on this page. So I might have problem, then please let me know :D

Hi. I start to learn Ubuntu for my University lecture.
I installed Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa) on Mac M1.

My problem is I can't find my WiFi icon on Ubuntu.
But, I think WiFi was connected, I can use Internet.

This is a result that used iwconfig.

```
virbr0-nic no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
virbr0    no wireless extensions.
enp0s1    no wireless extensions.
```

I'm novice so I was trying to figure out how I can handle this problem for 3 days.
But I failed.

I have no idea how does wifi work. Anyway, It works.

This is my question. Is there any problem for me using Ubuntu without WiFi Adaptor in this situation??